# Regex to validate numbers from 0 to 5 with up to 2 decimals

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all I am having a requirement where a textbox should allow numers from `1 to 5` along with decimals

```
Valid conditons : 1,2,3,4,5
Valid conditions : 0.1,0.02,0.5 ---- 4.99

InValid : -1,-2,-3,-4,-5 or 6 5.1 and so one
```

I tried this expression `^\d{1}[0-5](?:\.\d{1,2})?$` which didn't worked as expected so can some one help me

Comment: Modified your regex a bit: ^[0-5]{1}(\.\d{1,2})?$

Comment: didn't worked as expected `mgasparel`

Comment: Check out the answer from anouar.bag he fixed a mistake I made which allowed values all the way up to 5.99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
^([0-4]{1}(\.\d{1,2})?|5(.0{1,2})?)$
```

Comment: So you're not going to allow `5.00`?

Comment: FYI, if anyone needs more than 2 digits in the fractional part, replace both `{1,2}` with `+` (one or more).

Answer (score 1):

I think regex is somewhat overkill here, isn't it a simple `&&` will help you with this?

```
decimal _dec = 0.0m;
if ((_dec >= 0) && (_dec <= 5))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Valid");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
}
```

but if the value is a string, use `Decimal.TryParse()` to check if it a valid decimal number or not,

```
string _strDecimal = "3.5";
decimal _dec;
bool _valid = Decimal.TryParse(_strDecimal, out _dec);
if (_valid)
(
    if ((_dec >= 0) && (_dec <= 5))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valid");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
    }
)
esle
{
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: I need to validate from client side

Comment: here's a simple regex for that. `^[1-5](\.\d{1,2})?$`

Answer (score 0):

`^([0-4](\.\d{1,2})?|5)$` might do the trick if you only want to consider numbers with only two decimals, `^([0-4](\.\d+)?|5)$` otherwise.